# React Native pass data between two class component in two screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native

1. I have screen1 and screen2. In screen1, I have a class component A. In screen2, I have class component B. In A, I have the state "score", which I want to pass to B in screen2.
2. I've tried:

In screen1:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('screen2', {
   score: [this.state.score],
});
```

In screen2 :

```
const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('score');
```

It does not work. I think it's because react-navigation got updated.

3. I looked up https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/, but the examples are functions, not class components.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of `react-navigation` you can access the props passed to `screen2` in a class component like this:

`this.props.route.params.score`

Comment: Thank you! I used const data = this.props.route.params.score in screen2, but the error says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'step' of undefined". In screen1, I have this.props.navigation.navigate('screen2', {
   score: this.state.score,
});

Comment: Can you edit your question to show where you are accessing the 'step' property?